# Confusion about closed linear mapping and closed linear operator mapping.

Tags: functional-analysis

If a mapping closed then it means it maps closed maps onto closed maps.

On the other hand by Closed Graph Theorem, there is a notation that if a mapping has closed graph so it is closed operator.

My question is, when these two concepts are become the same?

And by closed graph theorem I know that if a linear operator $T:X\to X$, $X$ - is banach, has closed graph then it is continuous.

What about the linear closed mapping? (maps closed maps into closed maps) Can it be continuous $T:X\to X$ if $X$ is normed space, if not can we guarantee it is continuous when $X$ is Banach?